# SQL Query Problem -- Are Pivots Necessary?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregation

Given the following data:

```
CardholderID   Source                                   DateTime
-------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------------------
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-30 13:58:42.410
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_In_Reader                   2010-06-30 13:44:22.417
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-30 13:41:30.510
3              Lobby_To_Office_Reader                   2010-06-30 13:27:51.407
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-30 13:27:31.313
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_In_Reader                   2010-06-30 13:27:23.203
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-29 12:03:04.413
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_In_Reader                   2010-06-29 09:18:16.417
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-28 17:51:08.507
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_In_Reader                   2010-06-28 12:52:28.403
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_Out_Reader                  2010-06-28 12:04:36.407
3              2nd_Flr_Ramp_In_Reader                   2010-06-28 09:17:20.407
4              1St_Flr_To_Stairs_Reader                 2010-08-02 09:41:14.403
4              1St_Flr_Door_In_Reader                   2010-08-02 09:41:12.403
4              1St_Flr_Door_Out_Reader                  2010-07-30 18:24:36.400
4              1St_Flr_To_Stairs_Reader                 2010-07-30 14:09:54.403
4              1St_Flr_Door_In_Reader                   2010-07-30 14:09:48.403
4              1St_Flr_Door_Out_Reader                  2010-07-30 13:25:24.407
```

How can I obtain the minimum time for an "In" source and the maximum time for an "Out" source for each cardholderId by day.

The first thing I tried was

```
select CardHolderId, min(DateTime) as EarliestSwipe, null as LatestSwipe
from EventTable
where source like '%In_Reader%'
group by cardholderid, CardHolderFirstName, CardHolderLastName,dateadd(dd, (datediff(dd, 0, DateTime)),0)
union 
select CardHolderId, null as EarliestSwipe, max(DateTime) as LatestSwipe
from EventTable
where source like '%Out_Reader%'
group by cardholderid, CardHolderFirstName, CardHolderLastName, dateadd(dd, (datediff(dd, 0, DateTime)),0)
```

but I need the results of the two queries combined.  My question is, do I need to pivot the data to get the results that I desire or can I remain on the track of the example I provided. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to add a column for IN/OUT reader (like a bit column for "IsIn" or something) so you aren't doing a text comparison every time you need to run this query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
SELECT CardholderID,
    MIN(CASE WHEN source like '%In_Reader%' THEN DateTime ELSE NULL END) as EarliestSwipe,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source like '%Out_Reader%' THEN DateTime ELSE NULL END) as LatestSwipe,
FROM EventTable
GROUP BY CardholderID
```

I excluded your additional GROUP BY values, but I think they can be added.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. Note that "DateTime" is a reserved word in SQL, so if you can't rename that column--and you should--you'll have to [bracket] it everywhere you reference it.

Comment: It's not easy beating the experts here.  Good point on the "DateTime" comment.

Comment: You are awesome.  That was exactly what I needed. Thanks.  If I could give you more points for this I would.

Comment: @SideFX - I only do it for the good of the community...  haha, I couldn't even keep a straight face while typing this.  :)  Good luck.